# Integrate this abstract integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate(in this case: find an antiderivatie) $\int f(\sqrt{c^2+x^2})x\, dx$, where $f \in C$ and $F'=f$ for some $F' \in C^1$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

It seems to me as if I'm missing the trick for this integral. Does anybody here have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know a primitive (an antiderivative) $G$ of $F$, it is relatively easy by substituting $u = \sqrt{c^2+x^2}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\int f(\sqrt{c^2+x^2})x\,dx &= \int\sqrt{c^2+x^2}\cdot f(\sqrt{c^2+x^2}) \frac{x}{\sqrt{c^2+x^2}}\,dx\\
&= \int u\cdot f(u)\,du\\
&= u\cdot F(u) - \int F(u)\,du\\
&= u\cdot F(u) - G(u)\\
&= \sqrt{c^2+x^2}\cdot F(\sqrt{c^2+x^2}) - G(\sqrt{c^2+x^2}).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Mhmm, actually the excercise was supposed to be solved by only referring to this $F$. You think it is impossible to give an antiderivative that does not use this $G$?

Comment: Any two primitives of the integrand differ by a constant. So in general, it is not possible to express the result without $G$, unless $\int F(u)\,du$ counts, as far as I can see. If $F$ has a particular form, it can be possible of course.

Comment: Take $f(x) = 2xe^{x^2}$. Then $F(x) = e^{x^2}$ but this function in turn has no [normal] primitive and $G(u)$ and the final expression will not be expressible in terms of analytic functions. You need some extra conditions at least.

Comment: I'll see whether I can offer some extra conditions on F...thanks to you all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $F(x)$  is   the antiderivative   for $f(\sqrt{x}).$  Change  the  variable $t=x^2+c^2,  dt=2 x dx.$ Then
$$
\int f(\sqrt{x^2+c^2})x dx=\int f(\sqrt{t})  \frac 12 dt= \frac 12 F(t)= \frac{1}{2}F(\sqrt{x^2+c^2})+C.
$$